# mongoDB + Java-8: java.lang.NullPointerException: no value for: users

Tags: mongodb, java-8

Am new to Java, sorry if this obvious mistake. Also I tried to search all the questions related to my issue none of them solve it.

Am trying to fetch all documents in mongoDB collection and put them in array.
Am fetching the documents correctly I can print them all in the console:

```
 public List<Item> findAll() {
        List<Item> items = new ArrayList<>();
        try {
            collection.find().forEach(document -> {
                System.out.println(document);
            });
            return items;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Error fetcing all items  " + e);
            return items; // should be logging 
        }
    }
```

however when I add this two lines:

```
System.out.println(document);
Item item = new Item((BasicDBObject) document); //line causing the error
items.add(item);//line causing the error
```

I get this error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: no value for: users
```

The Item class code :

```
package io.app.item.model;

import com.mongodb.BasicDBObject;
import org.bson.types.ObjectId;

import java.util.Date;

public class Item {

    private final String id;
    private final String name;
    private final int users;
    private Date updated_at = new Date();
    private Date created_at = new Date();

    public Item(BasicDBObject dbObject) {
        this.id = ((ObjectId) dbObject.get("_id")).toString();
        this.name = dbObject.getString("name");
        this.users = dbObject.getInt("users");
        this.updated_at = dbObject.getDate("updated_at");
        this.created_at = dbObject.getDate("created_at");
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public int getUsers() {
        return users;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
}
```

I have commented out the `users` filed from the `Item` class then everything work not really work I still don't know why adding field of type `integer` causing the problem also when remove it the return was in this shape:

```
[io.app.item.model.Item@15457c60, io.app.item.model.Item@1238bd80]
```

Note am using mongoldb 3.4.1 driver.
Sample of document:

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "586140b25fa86a1e760d92fe"
    },
    "name": "item1",
    "created_at": {
        "$date": "2016-12-26T16:09:22.949Z"
    }
}
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the entire stack trace that goes with that null pointer exception. You should also include the source code for this `Item` class.

Comment: Added the item class code still trying to figure out how to include the stack trace.